# type casting in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a method takes an parameter of an object to print a number:

```
object target = Console.ReadLine();
PrintNumber(target);
public void PrintNumber(object target)
{
   int number = 0;
   if(int.TryParse(target.ToString(), out number))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(number);
   }
}
```

If I just want to use:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)target);
```

but it does't work and throw an exception, why we should use TryParse methods?

Comment: What do you it does not work? Does it throw an error when you do casting?

Answer (score 6):

> why we should use TryParse methods?

Because when you use the `TryParse` method, it will not throw an exception to your code **IF** the conversion fails. While if you cast it this way `(int)target`, it will throw an exception if the conversion to `int` fails

Comment: Just note that if target == null it will throw an exception when you try to call `.ToString()` - I believe TryParse also throws if you pass a null parameter.  It should probably be something like `(string)target ?? 0`, or add a null check before calling TryParse

Comment: Yes, if that's the case, you can just use the **Null-conditional Operator** of C# 6 to handle null checks. For example: `target?.ToString()`, this will prevent it from throwing an exception if the value of the object is null

Comment: That would work if you're using C# 6 - and null does not cause an exception here, so that's fine (or just using `(string)target`).

Comment: Yep. That would also do. :)

Comment: @prtdomingo but I didn't enter anything like "ABC", I entered an integer as an object, so why I cannot cast it back?

Comment: You didn't actually entered an `int` as an `object` if you pass the value "1" to your method. You're actually passing a string, and if that's the case, you have to convert the value to `int` in which the `int.TryParse` is doing for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast explicitly to the `Object` type this way. You need to use the `Convert` class.

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.toInt32(target));
```

Comment: but I didn't enter anything like "ABC", I entered an integer as an object, so why I cannot cast it back?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you entered, all it sees is "Object" as the type. It knows nothing about the contents, like if you gave it a string it doesn't have any idea that "this is an Object type, but the user gave a string so I'll allow string casting", it's just "Object"

Answer (score 1):

Just to flesh this out a little bit more -

Casting in C# will try to find an appropriate casting operator.  If the `target` object either is an `int` or has an appropriate casting operator (e.g. if it's a `byte` or `short`) then you're good - it will be properly converted at runtime.  However, if there is no operator, it will throw an `InvalidCastException` - such as if the `target` is a `string` (there's no good default way to cast `string`s to `int`s - what does the `string` "This is a string" cast to?).

Exceptions are great, but should be reserved for when something unexpected happens.  It shouldn't really be so unexpected that user input may or may not be numeric (or that any `string` may or may not be numeric).  So writing a `try/catch` block for this code is overkill and will be more resource intensive than if you could just somehow check if the `string` was numeric and make a decision (which is what you'd probably be trying to do with your `try/catch` block anyway).  You could do that by checking that the `string` isn't null and then running a RegEx on it or iterating the characters looking for a non-numeric character (this isn't super hard for `int`s but it gets more complicated with numbers that allow scientific notation, or number formats that allow or don't allow signs/whitespace/commas/decimals/etc.).  You could also try calling `.Parse()`, but that gets you back to the exception problem again (and remember: exceptions are more expensive to throw and catch than just checking a boolean).

So the .NET framework gives you a nicer alternative: `TryParse`.  Some overloads for some types even allow you to specify formats or styles (such as on `float.TryParse()` and `DateTime.TryParse() / DateTime.TryParseExact()`).  This way, you can more efficiently control program flow through checking a boolean, without reinventing the wheel every time you need to check whether a string is numeric or a date or a time etc.  And since most objects are readily convertible to strings, this works out much more nicely.  Your program can now make a decision about how to handle invalid input, rather than necessarily throwing an exception (which may be overkill).  Even if you really want to throw an exception if the input is not numeric, you can throw a better/more specific exception - instead of throwing `InvalidCastException`, you might throw something like a custom `ValidationFailureException` that has a nice message explaining what parameter/argument/node was incorrect.

One other option to consider is that if, for some reason, your method has to take an `object` (maybe it's conforming to an interface definition you can't modify), but you believe your input will normally be an int, you can do something like

```
var intTarget = target as int?
if (intTarget != null)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(intTarget); 
}
```

Note that since `as` can result in `null`, you have to use a nullable int.  This is probably not helpful in this particular scenario, since you'll want to end up using `TryParse` anyway if `as` fails - but it may be useful when you're dealing with more complicated objects that are classes which lack any framework-supplied `TryParse` methods.  But also note that this is more along the lines of casting than checking - `TryParse` works if the `object` really truly *is* a string that has numeric characters; `as` will only work if the `object` really truly *is* an `int` (or `int?`):

```
object target = "32";
var intTarget = target as int?; // intTarget == null
intTarget = int.Parse(target); // intTarget == 32;
target = 33;
intTarget = target as int?; // intTarget == 33
```